# Application not working in IE 8 compatibility mode

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer-8

I have developed an application in J2EE.My jsp pages work fine in IE 8 but as soon as IE enters the compatibility mode some of my jsp pages go haywire. I have tried modifying my  tag for this purpose but it is not working everywhere.Apart from this my app is working fine on both mozilla and chrome. Is there any other way by which I can cater to this problem and my app may be able to run on both IE-8 and IE-8 compatibility mode.
My meta tag has the following details

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"
```

Comment: *"as soon as IE enters the compatibility mode some of my jsp pages go haywire."* .... so the simple answer is not to use compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution here is to avoid compatibility mode at all costs. (and avoid quirks mode too, for that matter).

1. Make sure you have a valid DOCTYPE at the top of your page, and that your HTML code is valid. (use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to test this)

   If you're not sure of the doctype to use, use this one:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   This will avoid the browser going into quirks mode.
2. Use IE's **edge** mode to force the browser to use the best mode available:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                                                   ^^
                                               this is the important bit!
   ```

   This will avoid the browser going into compatibility mode.

Hope that helps.